# FullText Search With utf-8 error PHP/MySql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

This's my code

```
$sql="select * from data where match(name,post) against(CONVERT('".$search."' USING utf8)) ";
```

but it's not working with utf8 character ex: á, ă, đinh, công, mạnh....

i tried this code, but it's not working too

```
$sql="select * from data where match(name,post) against('$search') ";
```

SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH SKILL :v

Comment: I think you need to use `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");`.